# Objective-C and use of SEL/IMP

Tags: objective-c

Another question of mine about [optimizing Objective C programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534990/objective-c-optimization) inspired the following: does anyone have a short example using SEL and IMP when theMethod has two (or more) integers for input?

Comment: Can you give more details? I'm not sure what you mean by SEL and IMP.

Comment: Yeah, what, exactly, do you want to do?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here's a [good tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/02/imp-of-current-method.html) for getting the current IMP (with an overview of IMPs).  A very basic example of IMPs and SELs is:

```
- (void)methodWithInt:(int)firstInt andInt:(int)secondInt { NSLog(@"%d", firstInt + secondInt); }

SEL theSelector = @selector(methodWithInt:andInt:);
IMP theImplementation = [self methodForSelector:theSelector]; 
//note that if the method doesn't return void, you have to explicitly typecast the IMP, e.g. int(* foo)(id, SEL, int, int) = ...
```

You could then invoke the IMP like so:

```
theImplementation(self, theSelector, 3, 5);
```

There's usually no reason to need IMPs unless you're doing serious voodoo--is there something specific you want to do?

Comment: @eman: you need to cast that return so: void (* theImplementation)(id,SEL,int,int) = (void (*)(id,SEL,int,int))[self methodForSelector:theSelector];

Comment: @Jason Coco-Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think IMP is typedef'd as (id, SEL, ...), so it shouldn't matter (although it's not typesafe, but if you need typesafety, you probably shouldn't be using IMPs).

Comment: You are right, since this method is void it is ok, but you will get errors in many other instances. You /need/ to cast was probably too strong, you /should always cast/ is probably more correct ;)--but given this question itself, my guess is that the OP probably /should not/ be using IMP either.

Comment: @Jason Coco: Good point, didn't think of that (updated example).

Comment: Many thanks for the replies. You're absolutely correct that I definitely do not need this for my code but I was curious. I also thought it may be of interest more generally as I couldn't get the syntax right for more than one input.

Comment: There are other subtleties that make it important to cast the IMP to the right function type before calling it. For instance, the C calling convention for vararg function requires that `float`s be promoted to `double`s, so if you pass a `float` to an uncasted IMP that expects a `float`, it will be promoted to a `double` and you'll get incorrect results/crashes.

Comment: What is the purpose/benefits of SEL/IMP?

Comment: This was crashing for me when the selector was return type void.  To get it to work I had to lose `IMP` and use a literal function pointer `(void (*myFunc)(id, SEL, ...)) = (void (*)(id, SEL, ...))[self methodForSelector:theSelector]`

Comment: @shosti, from the Apple docs, if you want to send one particular message to an object (or a group of similar objects, say in an array) many times, this speeds up the process, because it avoids having to lookup the message address.

Comment: Hi, I think this answer may be outdated. Because "theImplementation(self, theSelector, 3, 5);" throws a compiler error for me.

Answer (score 2):

Now that I have this working thanks to eman, I can add yet another example:

`SEL cardSelector=@selector(getRankOf:::::::);`

`IMP rankingMethod=[eval methodForSelector:cardSelector];`

`rankingMethod(eval, cardSelector, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);`

I don't need this for anything useful, I just needed to satisfy my curiosity! Thank you again.

Comment: Another good link on optimising Objective-C is
http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-3-imp-deluxe.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible alternative. This avoids the crash but stubbing doesn't work.

```
- (void)setUp
{
   [super setUp];

   [self addSelector@selector(firstName) toClass:[User class]];
   [self addSelector@selector(lastName) toClass:[User class]];
}

- (void)addSelector:(SEL)selector toClass:(Class)class
{
    NSString *uniqueName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", NSStringFromClass(class), NSStringFromSelector(selector)];
    SEL sel = sel_registerName([uniqueName UTF8String]);
    IMP theImplementation = [class methodForSelector:sel];
    class_addMethod(class, selector, theImplementation, "v@:@");
}
```