# Getting the address of an Objective-C method

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, function-pointers

I am new to Objective-C and I need to overcome the following issue.
I am trying to develop a front-end for a C library and I need to somehow get the address of an Objective-C member function and pass it to the library.

For instance: here's what I would do in C++

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    void my function();
    void some_other_function()
    { connect_signal(my_function); }
};
```

Here, I just pass the address of `my_function()` to connect_signal.
Is that possible in Objective-C? Any other ideas?

My second choice would be to simply write a C function out of the class that would call the Objective-C function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s a `methodForSelector:` method that returns an `IMP`, a pointer to the implementation of a method for given selector ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650190/objective-c-and-use-of-sel-imp)). Is that what you’re after?

And as a more general remark, using a pointer to a method implementation is usually too much magic. Is there a higher-level, more “ordinary” solution to your use case? (I can’t really imagine the details from what you wrote in the question.)

Comment: So, if I got everything right, I should just get the IMP of the current function by first obtaining the selector, and then cast that IMP to a C function pointer?

Comment: `IMP` already is a C function pointer: `typedef id (*IMP)(id self, SEL _cmd, ...)`. The first argument is the object, the second one is the selector being called. This signature might or might not be a problem depending on your C code.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, you can't connect a signal to a nonstatic C++ function. At least not in the *nix meaning of signals. Those need a `this` pointer for invokation.

Now, about Objective C. Depends on what do you want to do - pass a pointer to an Objective C method to a plain-C API, or implement a signal-like callback mechanism of your own. Other answers concentrate on the former; let's talk the latter.

The natural thing to do is passing around a combination of a selector and an object pointer. Selectors have datatype `SEL` and are retrieved using the @selector() construct. A selector is a piece of data (really an integer) that uniquely identifies a method within a class hierarchy.

Let's imagine you have a `connect_signal` function somewhere that wants a callback:

```
-(void)connect_signal:(SEL)callbackSelector forObject:(NSObject*)callbackObject;
```

You call it like this (from within the callback object):

```
[xx connect_signal:@selector(MyMethod:) forObject:self];
```

Within the function, you save the selector and the object pointer. When you need to invoke the callback, you would issue the following call:

```
[SavedCallbackObject performSelector:(SavedCallbackSelector) withObject: nil];
```

The second parameter is for passing parameters to the callback; if you need more than one, see NSInvoke.

My answer is assuming Cocoa. NSObject, e. g. is a Cocoa class. It's a safe bet for ObjC questions these days, considering.

Or you can use good old function pointers. They're still around.

Answer (score 2):

An Objective-C method implementation (IMP) is a C function that takes *at least* two arguments; the target of the method call (self) and the selector to be invoked (_cmd).

Thus, passing an IMP to your C API won't work.

Your best bet is to pass a C function.   Assuming your C API is sensible and has an "arbitrary user context pointer thingy", something like:

```
void myfunc(void *context) {
    [(MyClass *)context callback];
}
```