# Call function pointer from selector

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSMenuItem`, and I create it using this:

```
NSMenuItem* nsMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:menuItem->getText()] action: keyEquivalent:@""];
```

Now I pass in a function pointer, which I want to call when the selector gets invoked.

How do I do this?

I have tried:

```
id block = [^{
             functionPointer();
             } copy];
        
NSMenuItem* nsMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:menuItem->getText()] action:@selector(invoke) keyEquivalent:@""];
[nsMenuItem setTarget:block];
```

However, the menu item is still grayed out.

How do I pass in a function pointer as a selector?

I'm building a cross platform app, and so basically I call to create a new menu, and my core C++ code will pass in a function pointer for the Menu Item.

Comment: watch out for the types "IMP" and "SEL" in objective-C [use of IMP and SEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650190/objective-c-and-use-of-sel-imp)

Comment: is this code above meant to be used as objective-c or objective-c++ ? In other words i assume you want to call a c++ function (IMP) given to the menuItem as Selector (SEL) applied on a object (id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand how menus work. Did you read the documentation? Especially the section about [enabling menu items](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html) is very insightful.

To give a short overview: the *selector* is the *name* of a function that will be called when the menu item is invoked. It's not a function, it's the name of a function. In Smalltalk one would say it is the *message* to be send.

The *target* is the object that is receiving the message.

The Menu mechanism checks if the target implements the selector function. Since your target is a block, it does not implement any function at all, hence the menu item is always disabled.

What you need do is the following:

- store the block to be executed somewhere
- add a generic selector like "performBlock" to your menu item
- set the class that stores the block as a target
- in that class, implement a fuction `performBlock` and call the block there

---

You could subclass `NSMenuItem` and keep the block in there, see this example [here](https://gist.github.com/smokyonion/6077259).

Comment: I'm building a cross platform app, and so basically I call to create a new menu, and my core C++ code will pass in a function pointer for the Menu Item. That's why I cannot set the class

Comment: You need to create a wrapper class with a `performBlock` (arbitrary name) function that just holds the function pointer, and set this as the target. Or you could subclass `NSMenuItem` and do the stuff in there.

Comment: Yeah, I just created a wrapper class with that. The issue is when I call [[WrapperClass alloc] init], it automatically gets destroyed

Comment: Check out subclassing (see my edits above), this helps against ARC cleanup