# Command Line Tools with XCode 5

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, homebrew

I just updated to XCode 5, and as homebrew told me my gcc was out of date, I updated it. However, now when I type

```
gcc
```

into terminal, I get:

```
clang: error: no input files
```

Is that behavior to be expected? I'm used to seeing something along the lines of:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
```

(I'm running OS X 10.8.5, by the way.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default compiler for Xcode since Xcode 4 is `clang`.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344328/is-llvm-the-default-compiler-in-xcode-4) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. So the error it's throwing is just clang being more verbose than llvm?

Comment: You are way better off using clang, see [here](http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html#gcc) ;)

Comment: @ppaulojr In addition to your answer: in Xcode 5 clang is the only compiler ;)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 command line tools may be downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

"Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) For Xcode - Late October"

There might be a command line way, but I haven't tried it:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/how-to-download-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode-without-the-downloads-for-devel